# JOIN with records in two tables

Tags: sql-server

I want to do a query to return something like this

```
Table 1
Id1    Name
  1    A
  2    B
  3    C
  4    D
  5    E   

 Table 2
    Id2
    10
    11
    12
```

I need to go to table2 and return each record in Table1 like this:

```
Id1 Name Id2
1    A   10
2    B   11
3    C   12
4    D   10
5    E   11
```

When I finish the records in Table2, I start again until completing the records in Table1
Thanks!

Comment: So. How do you decide which rows in `Table2` goes in `Table1` ? From what I can gather, cyclically ?

Comment: I just want to split the records without any condition

Comment: I do not find a pattern in your **table2**, if you do not want to use the Cartesian product then I do not know any other way to do. Can you explain a little better what should be in the table2?

Comment: In table2 I have only Ids that I want to split

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this query, this works perfectly (here is the **[link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/21698/5)** for you to try)

```
WITH tempTable1 AS
(
    SELECT
        b.ID2,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID2) AS position1
    FROM
        TABLE2 b
)
SELECT x.ID1, x.NAME, isnull((SELECT b.id2 FROM tempTable1 b WHERE b.position1 = (x.position2 % (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tempTable1))),
(SELECT TOP 1 y.id2 FROM tempTable1 y ORDER BY y.position1 desc)) AS ID2
FROM (
SELECT A.ID1, A.NAME, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A.ID1) AS position2
FROM TABLE1 A
) X
```

This query I do not like it, but I could not make another :(